# Filter listbox with textbox

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Right now i have a listbox who contains users. But in this case i would need a filter function where i will be able to write "jo" and get all the users who start with "jo" in the list. This seems like to be a bigger problem than i thought. I have tried both vid jquery and from the controller. Like you can see below my controller method who fills the list is a GET method, do i need a POST-variant of it?

IF its possible, i would like to have the users coming in the list in like real-time. Is it possible?

```
   *CONTROLLER*
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Meeting(string txtValue)
    {

        var filteredUsers = SearchUser(txtValue);

        var users = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var item in filteredUsers)
        {
            users.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.UserFirstname + " " + item.UserLastname,
                Value = item.UserID
            });
        }

        var meetingView = new MeetingViewModel
        {
            Users = users,
            SelectedUsers = new List<SelectListItem>()
        };

        return View(meetingView);
    }



    *FILTER FUNCTION IN CONTROLLER*
     public List<UserModel> SearchUser (string txtValue)
    {
        var ctx = new DB();

        var users = ctx.Users
                    .Where(u => u.UserFirstname.Contains(txtValue) ||
                    u.UserLastname.Contains(txtValue) ||
                    txtValue == null).ToList();

        return users;
    }


    *VIEW*
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Meeting", "Meeting", FormMethod.Get))
        {
                @Html.TextBox("txtValue", null, new { placeholder = "Input 
    value" })
                <input type="button" value="Search" />
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: Updated the code... missed a bit

Comment: You can check to use Ajax request

Comment: You can check this to find what you want: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-in-asp-net/

Comment: But is it possible to change the view like this?

Comment: You can use Javascript to update the view to modify it when the ajax request is finished

Comment: This seems to be high level coding, do you have any idea how to implement it using my code?

Comment: It will be impossible without using Javascript or you need to reload the page